# How to enable copy and paste of numbers from latex documents with cfr-lm?

Tags: lmodern

I have an issue when copying and pasting numbers from a PDF generated with pdflatex (pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018/W32TeX)) and Acrobat Reader/Acrobat Professional. Also reported at https://github.com/latextemplates/LNCS/issues/22.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\obeylines

\begin{document}
Normal number: 100.
Math mode number: $100$.
\end{document}
```

Acrobat Professional copy result:

```
Normal number: 322.
Math mode number: 100.
```

With `oldstyle=false`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[rm={oldstyle=false}]{cfr-lm}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\obeylines

\begin{document}
Normal number: 100.
Math mode number: $100$.
\end{document}
```

Result:

```
Normal number: .
Math mode number: 100.
```

[image: paste result]

With lmodern, everything works as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\obeylines

\begin{document}
Normal number: 100.
Math mode number: $100$.
\end{document}
```

Result:

```
Normal number: 100.
Math mode number: 100.
```

### Notes

Note that this issue does not appear with SumatraPDF.

This issue also happens with [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) in Firefox. Also, using lualatex (LuaTeX, Version 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2018/W32TeX)) does not help.

It also happens with the documentation of cfr-lm. Go to http://texdoc.net/pkg/cfr-lm (with Firefox), copy "Version 1.5 - 2015-02-01". The pasted result is: "Version 3.7 — 4237–24–23"

Comment: Why do you insist on using [tag:pdftex] when we have [tag:luatex]/[tag:xetex] and [tag:fontspec]? I'm sure whatever this package does can also be done with fontspec.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Okular either. I wouldn't recommend using this package with LuaTeX: in that case, use `fontspec`. There's no reason to use `cfr-lm` in that case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use glyphtounicode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}
\input glyphtounicode
\pdfgentounicode=1
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\obeylines
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
1234567890 copied: 1234567890

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a case, where [cmap](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cmap) does not help. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: You don't need to load `fontenc` here. Do you think `cfr-lm` should load `glyphtounicode`? (Conditionally, if pdfTeX is used?)